# Similar data from two different websites behaving differently in JSON

Tags: json

so I have 2 URL's which return basic sets of JSOn data. however, when I try to use them in a script, one returns data with a document.write and one doesn't

here are the two scripts

(working) http://jsfiddle.net/6ZeJ8/3/

```
$.getJSON("https://graph.facebook.com/btaylor", function(person){

$.each(person, function(key, value){
        document.write(key+": "+value+"<br />"); 
    });
});
```

(not working) http://jsfiddle.net/6ZeJ8/748/

```
$.getJSON("http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?        country=US&currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=StatTrak%E2%84%A2%20P250%20%7C%20Steel%20Disruption%20%28Factory%20New%29", function(person){

$.each(person, function(key, value){
        document.write(key+": "+value+"<br />"); 
    });
});
```

are they not exactly the same except for the URL's which both have basic JSON data?

Answer (score 0):

The second requests fails on [Same Domain Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) validation.

> The policy permits scripts running on pages originating from the same
>   site – a combination of scheme, hostname, and port number – to
>   access each other's DOM with no specific restrictions, but prevents
>   access to DOM on different sites The same-origin policy also applies to XMLHttpRequests unless the
>   server provides an Access-Control-Allow-Origin (CORS) header.

The first one passes because facebook returns `access-control-allow-origin:*` http header.